# Error while running a model in R

Tags: r, analytics, random-forest

> Error: water.exceptions.H2OModelBuilderIllegalArgumentException: Illegal argument(s) for DRF model: DRF_model_R_1485775621321_2.  Details: ERRR on field: _ntrees: The tree model will not fit in the driver node's memory (3.9 MB per tree x 400 > 1.50 GB) - try decreasing ntrees and/or max_depth or increasing min_rows!

```
local=h2o.init(nthreads=2,max_mem_size='5G')
data_r=as.h2o(data.matrix(data_tr))
rn_clf=h2o.randomForest(feature.names,
                'log.Sales',
                training_frame=data_r,
                ntrees=400,
                max_depth=28,
                nbins_cats = 1115                    
               )}
```

Is there any other way to resolve this other than decreasing ntrees or max_depth?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, either reduce features or nbins_cat (determine optimum nbins_cats first) or increase RAM size, maxmimum depth is very high you must reduce this,